# Task.WaitAll freezes app C#

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I wanted to try out Threading.Task (C#) to run some work in parallel. In this simple example I have a form with progress bar and button. On click the RunParallel function is called. Without Task.WaitAll() it seems to run through fine. However, with the WaitAll statement the form shows and nothing happens. I dont understand what I am doing wrong in the setup below.
Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
{
    public delegate void BarDelegate();
    public MainWindow()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunParallel();
    }
    private void RunParallel() {
        int numOfTasks = 8;
        progressBar1.Maximum = numOfTasks;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        try
        { 
            List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; i++)
            {
                allTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { doWork(i); }));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(allTasks.ToArray());
        }
        catch { }  
    }
    private void doWork(object o1)
    {
        // do work...
        // then
        this.Invoke(new BarDelegate( UpdateBar )); 
    }
    private void UpdateBar()
    {
        if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum) progressBar1.Value++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Task.WaitAll is a blocking operation. Use ContinueWith or ContinueWhenAll methods instead

Comment: That's what WaitAll does, it blocks until all tasks have finished. The tasks can't finish because Invoke will run its action on the UI thread, which is already blocked by WaitAll

Answer (score 11):

You are waiting on the UI thread. This freezes the UI. Don't do that.

In addition, you are deadlocking because `Invoke` waits for the UI thread to unblock.

My advice: use `async/await` if at all possible.

And *please* do not swallow exceptions. You're creating future work for yourself that way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide an example for async/await?

Comment: I could only provide very short advice at this place. I'd rather direct you to https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=c%23+winforms+await so that you have more comprehensive information.

Answer (score 4):

That's what WaitAll does, it blocks until all tasks have finished. The tasks can't finish because Invoke will run its action on the UI thread, which is already blocked by WaitAll

To make your code really run asynchronously, try something like this:

```
private void RunParallel() {
    int numOfTasks = 8;
    progressBar1.Maximum = numOfTasks;
    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    try
    { 
        var context=TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>DoWork(i))
                    .ContinueWith(()=>UpdateBar(),context);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    { 
      MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString(),"AAAAAARGH");
    }  
}
private void DoWork(object o1)
{
    // do work...

}
private void UpdateBar()
{
    if (progressBar1.Value < progressBar1.Maximum) progressBar1.Value++;
}
```

In this case, UpdateBar is called on the UI context each time a task finishes without causing any blocking.

Note, this is not production code, just a way to show how you can run a method asynchronously and update the UI without blocking. You *do* need to read about Tasks to understand what they do and how they work.

Using `async/await` in .NET 4.5+ you can write this in a much simpler way. The following will execute DoWork in the background without blocking, but still update the UI each time a Task finishes.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int numOfTasks = 8;
        progressBar1.Maximum = numOfTasks;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfTasks; i++)
            {
                await Task.Run(() => DoWork(i));
                UpdateBar();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString(), "AAAAAARGH");
        }
    }
```

`await` tells the compiler to generate code to execute anything below it ont the original (UI) threadwhen the task to its right finishes:

Comment: A good answer, but I really cannot upvote telling beginners to `catch (Exception)` and then continue on as if nothing is wrong.

Comment: Nobody is telling beginners to "continute as if nothing is wrong". In fact, I do say **this is not production code**. As for what you would do, it does depend on the scenarion I think: on a desktop app you tell the user, log and probably try to recover, or allow the application to die. On a server application perhaps you return no results but log the problem and send an alert to the administrator. On a demo application allowing the app to crash or showing it to the programmer is enough to allow him to fix the code and retry

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis! The C#4.5 example works great. However, after the for loop I want to wait till every task completed. How do I have to restructure this then?

Comment: You can use [Task.WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) to wait asynchronously for all the tasks you pass to finish and then execute code on the UI thread, eg: `await Task.WhenAll(myTasks);` .

Answer (score 1):

In doWork you call `this.Invoke(...)` which waits for UI thread to process messages. Unfortunatelly you UI thread is not processing messages because it is waiting for all `doWork(...)` to finish.

Easiest fix is to change `this.Invoke` to `this.BeginInvoke` (it will send messages but no wait for them to be processed) in doWork.
Although, I have to admin it is still not by-the-book as UI should not wait for anything.
Simple pattern (pre async/await era):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    ... work ...
})
.ContinueWith((t) => {
    ... updating UI (if needed) ...
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

`RunParallel` blocks until all the tasks are completed. Use a different mechanism to notify the UI.